# Pycharm pygmsh error AssertionError: Gmsh exited with error (return code 3221225781)

Tags: python, pycharm

I've been trying to run the 2nd example on the pygmsh website (https://pypi.org/project/pygmsh/), but I keep getting errors. First the file couldn't be found and I got the error 'file not found, can't find the specified file', but now that I've solved that part, I get this new error **(AssertionError: Gmsh exited with error (return code 3221225781).**
According to some people, I'm missing`enter code here` a .dll file, but I literally just reinstalled gmsh again without errors. I can see gmsh is added to the interpreter path inside my venv, I even added a path directly to gmsh.exe, but I still get this error message.

I'm working with **Pycharm** (up to date version) on windows 10.

```
import pygmsh

geom = pygmsh.opencascade.Geometry(
  characteristic_length_min=0.1,
  characteristic_length_max=0.1,
  )

rectangle = geom.add_rectangle([-1.0, -1.0, 0.0], 2.0, 2.0)
disk1 = geom.add_disk([-1.2, 0.0, 0.0], 0.5)
disk2 = geom.add_disk([+1.2, 0.0, 0.0], 0.5)
union = geom.boolean_union([rectangle, disk1, disk2])

disk3 = geom.add_disk([0.0, -0.9, 0.0], 0.5)
disk4 = geom.add_disk([0.0, +0.9, 0.0], 0.5)
flat = geom.boolean_difference([union], [disk3, disk4])

geom.extrude(flat, [0, 0, 0.3])

mesh = pygmsh.generate_mesh(geom, gmsh_path = 'D:/Data/Documenten/TUD/ME/AFEM/venv/Lib/site-packages/gmsh-4.6.0-Windows64-sdk/bin/gmsh.exe')
```

```
D:\Data\Documenten\TUD\ME\AFEM\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Data/Documenten/TUD/ME/AFEM/stdFEM/geometrytest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Data/Documenten/TUD/ME/AFEM/stdFEM/geometrytest.py", line 21, in <module>
    mesh = pygmsh.generate_mesh(geom, gmsh_path = 'D:/Data/Documenten/TUD/ME/AFEM/venv/Lib/site-packages/gmsh-4.6.0-Windows64-sdk/bin/gmsh.exe')
  File "D:\Data\Documenten\TUD\ME\AFEM\venv\lib\site-packages\pygmsh\helpers.py", line 133, in generate_mesh
    assert p.returncode == 0, "Gmsh exited with error (return code {}).".format(
AssertionError: Gmsh exited with error (return code 3221225781).

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What's the name of the dll file you're missing? And according to whom?

Comment: I have no idea which dll to be honest. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42744 
I just looked at the 1st answer of this tread, but couldn't bring up any argument to question it since I have no experience in this field.